# Direct limit commutes with direct sums in the category of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, direct-sum, limits-colimits

I want to show that direct limit commutes with direct sums in the category of abelian groups. (I need this when studying algebraic topology)
 To do this, I first need a concise setting to start a proof, but I got stuck with this.

Let $\{G_\alpha , f_\alpha^\beta \}$ and $\{H_i,g_i^j\}$  be directed systems of abelian groups, with directed index sets $A$ and $I$, respectively. Then we have to  show that the direct sum of the direct limit groups of these two directed systems are isomorphic to the direct limit group of the system $\{G_\alpha \oplus H_i, f_\alpha^\beta \oplus g_i^j \}$.

My question is

1. Actually I'm not sure that my assertion is true. Is it true?
2. Is my setting valid?
3. If 1 is true,  then it seems to be this isomorphism is natural. Is it right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote the direct limit of $\left\{G_\alpha , f_\alpha^\beta \right\}$ as $G$, and the direct limit of $\left\{H_i,g_i^j\right\}$ as $H$. Then we claim that $G\oplus H$ is the direct limit of $\left\{G_\alpha \oplus H_i, f_\alpha^\beta \oplus g_i^j \right\}$. And your questions are answered by this claim.

The morphisms $G_\alpha\oplus H_i\rightarrow G\oplus H$ are induced by the morphisms $G_\alpha\rightarrow G$ and $H_i\rightarrow H$.

Suppose there is a compatible system of morphisms $G_\alpha\oplus H_i\rightarrow M$. Since $\operatorname{Hom}(G_\alpha\oplus H_i,M)\cong\operatorname{Hom}(G_\alpha, M)\oplus\operatorname{Hom}(H_i, M)$, this induces compatible systems of morphisms $G_\alpha\rightarrow M$ and $H_i\rightarrow M$. Then by the universal property of the direct limit, these morphisms factor through $G_\alpha\rightarrow G$ and $H_i\rightarrow H$. This immediately implies that the morphisms $G_\alpha\oplus H_i\rightarrow M$ factor through $G_\alpha\oplus H_i\rightarrow G\oplus H$. Therefore $G\oplus H$ is the direct limit of $\left\{G_\alpha \oplus H_i, f_\alpha^\beta \oplus g_i^j \right\}$ as claimed.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this result also hold true if we have a direct sum of an infinite number of abelian groups?